# identity callback path in production Azure website?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a asp.net core 2 mvc app with openid connect authentication. It works locally in Visual Studio Debug to IIS Express.
After I deploy to Azure, I see this error: invalid_request: The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid

This is my appsettings callback path:   "/Identity/AuthResult/" 
do i need to put in a full URI ,like https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/Identity/AuthResult/   ?

this is my startup code: `            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

```
        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";         // Microsoft identity platform
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false; // accept several tenants (here simplified)
        });`
```

I am following this wiki  [Quickstart: Add sign-in with Microsoft to an ASP.NET Core web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp#option-2-register-and-manually-configure-your-application-and-code-sample)

Comment: You need to configure the full URI in Azure AD (find the app registration's reply URLs)

Comment: Thanks for the reply
In my app registration, i have the full path 
example :  https://  /mysite-staging.azurewebsites.net/Identity/AuthResult/"

, which seems to match the error message path.
does the  appsettings callback path , which is relative ( "/Identity/AuthResult/" ) need to be a full path too ?

Comment: No the appsettings callback path is always relative. It'll give you an error if you try to set an absolute path.

Comment: When the error happens, the URL in your address bar will contain the redirect_uri it tried to use. You can compare that to what you have in AAD.